# Yii2 Parameterizing Routes other languages

Tags: php, routes, yii2, multilingual

```
   'GET /<controller:(konto|aktywacja)>' => 'user/<controller>/reset',
```

The problem is that i have controller named in english but site is writtng in polish language.

```
class AccountController extends Controller
```

I don't know how to translate the controller for routing matching in yii2 framework.

I want make parameterized route for better perfomance and less rules in config.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/i18n-selecting-application-language.md)

Comment: Or [here](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls)

Comment: I found this before , and it not solve my problem. I want just make paramterized route flexible but other language is problem. '<controller:(konto)>/<action> => <controller>(english)/<action>